# How can I convert a SO answer (or tag wiki) to a documentation example?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

I have [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227347/how-can-i-detect-the-dimensions-of-an-object-under-an-angle-in-this-picture-in-m/32228759#32228759) which is quite detailed and I wrote it as a mini-tutorial. IMHO, it fits (maybe with minor touches) to serve as a documentation example.

To make matters more interesting, how about **converting a tag wiki into a documentation example?** The wiki of [`bsxfun`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bsxfun/info) is basically a list of small examples...

Is there a way to "convert" an existing answer to a document example?
Or, can I post a "link only" example in documentation?
Should this be a "feature" of posting an answer as an example?

Comment: There is no way to convert it. If it's your answer, you can decide whether you want to reproduce it in full, or add a summary with a link to the original. (Either way, I suggest removing the "Welcome to Stack Overflow" meta-stuff from the top of the answer.)